# MS Project Change Text Color in Row based on Status Field

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting, text-formatting, microsoft-project

I am looking to change the color of the text for an entire row based on what is indicated in the "Status" field.

I have searched other forums and have found solutions that are close, but nothing that really does what I am looking for.  I am aware of the highlight feature and of the conditional formatting, but I can't get them to do what I need. I wrote some VB code to do this exact thing about 5 years ago, but I am a novice, it took me about 5 days to write the very basic code, and then I lost it when I left my last job. :-(

So, I am looking to just have some VBA that will do the following:

- If Status = "Late" then color the text in the row to "RED"
- If Status = "On Schedule" then color the text in the row to "GREEN"
- If Status = "Future Task" then color the text in the row to "BLACK"
- If Status = "Complete" then color the text in the row to "GRAY"

I would love to get advanced and have something like the following:
If Status = "On Schedule",  AND   % complete is < 85%,  AND   "Finish Date" is < 5 days in future,  then color the text in the row "ORANGE"

Comment: Sounds like a job for conditional formatting. What have you tried that didn't work? How didn't it work? In Excel, for instance, selecting your data area and using conditional formatting on the column using a formula `=$E1="Late"` will check all your selected area column E for the value and then apply formatting to the entire row. I'm not too adept at project as I don't have it.

Comment: Yes,  MS Project does not have the same "Conditional Formatting" type of function as Excel does.

Comment: You didn't answer any of the questions

Answer (score 0):

Sub CompletePercentSub()

Dim t As Task
Dim i As Integer

'Iterates  through the entire ms project file

i = 1
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks

```
SelectRow Row:=i, RowRelative:=False

If Not t Is Nothing Then

    Select Case t.Status
        Case 0 'Complete
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&H98FB98 'LIGHT GREEN
        Case 1 'On Schedule
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HE0FFFF 'TAN
        Case 2 'Late
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HC0FF& 'LIGHT RED
        Case 2 'Future Task
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF 'WHITE
    End Select
End If
```

i = i + 1

Next t

End Sub

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly.